# ffmpeg: isolate one audio channel

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, mono

How can I use `ffmpeg` to isolate one channel from an audio file? I have a stereo audio file, and I need the output to be the contents of the right channel in a mono audio file.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You have two methods:

## pan audio filter

The pan audio filter is powerful but the syntax takes some time to understand.

**It is helpful to refer to the channel layouts list when using pan:** `ffmpeg -layouts`

Stereo right channel to mono:

```
ffmpeg -i stereo.wav -af "pan=mono|FC=FR" right_mono.wav
```

...which is the same as:

```
ffmpeg -i stereo.wav -af "pan=1|c0=c1" right_mono.wav
```

- `mono` is output channel layout or number of channels. Alternatively you could use `1` instead of `mono`.
- `FC=FR` create the **F**ront **C**enter channel of the output from the **F**ront **R**ight of the input.
- `c0=c1` is the same as the above in this case: create the first (and only) channel of the mono output (`c0`) from the second channel (`c1`) of the input.
- If you want the left channel instead use `FC=FL` or `c0=c0`.

More info:

- [pan audio filter documentation](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#pan)
- [FFmpeg Wiki: Audio Channel Manipulation](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/AudioChannelManipulation) for many more examples

---

## -map_channel

You can use the `-map_channel` option. It uses pan in the background and is somewhat less flexible.

```
ffmpeg -i stereo.wav -map_channel 0.0.1 right_mono.wav
```

- The first `0` is the input file ID
- The next `0` is the stream specifier
- The `1` is the channel ID

So this can be translated as: first file, first stream, second channel (or right channel).

From the [`-map_channel`](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Advanced-options) documentation:

> The order of the `-map_channel` option specifies the order of the
>   channels in the output stream. The output channel layout is guessed
>   from the number of channels mapped (mono if one `-map_channel`, stereo
>   if two, etc.

Comment: Interstingly, on FLAC/WAV files `-map_channel` is nearly instantaneous saying "Pure channel mapping detected".

Comment: @Louis See [Remapping examples](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#Remapping-examples) for an explanation of "Pure channel mapping detected".

Comment: Ah nice, so pan seems superior in that it can do pure channel mapping on lossy files too.

Comment: I guess a shell command line would need some quotation around `pan=mono|FC=FR` or `pan=1|c0=c1` in order not to misinterpret the piping character `|`, wouldn't it?

Comment: @BernhardBodenstorfer Yes, it's recommended. I updated the answer. Looks like I was being lazy when I later added the pan section and didn't test it.